# Is there a way access instance itself reference in method?

Tags: c#, reference, instance, instance-methods

I have 2 class: Customer.class and Order.class. In Order.class has a field Customer customer; In customer class has a method CreateOrder, create a new order, and then set this customer as its customer, and then return order just created. Is there a way to do this?

This is C# class homework.

```
class Customer{
    public int ID{get; set;}
    public String Name{get; set;}
    public Array<Order> OrderArray{get; set;}
    public Order createOrder(){
        Order order = new Order(){Customer this.customer} //TODO
        OrderArray.add(order);
        return order;
    }
}
class Order{
    public int ID{get; set;}
    public Customer Customer{get; set;}
    public override String ToString(){
        return "Order["+ID+"] is ordered by "+Customer.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're pretty close. Try this: `new Order(){ Customer = this };`

Comment: The "name" of the instance associated with the an instance method, within that method is `this`.so: `Order order = new Order () {Customer = this };`